# Механизм работы метода islice() вместе с count() (itertools)

Tags: python, python-3.x, итераторы

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как работает itertools.islice() вместе с itertools.count().
Есть простой код:

```
import itertools

for elem in itertools.islice(itertools.count(50, 2), 10):
    print(elem, end=' ')
```

Что происходит?

1) При каждом вызове next() итератора islice() будет вызван next() итератора 
count(), пока islice() не вернет 10 элементов, затем StopIteration.

ИЛИ ЖЕ

2) Сначала islice() сразу попросит первые 10 элементов у count(), сгенерирует с них iterable и будет при вызове next() возвращать последовательно значения, пока элементы не закончатся

Интересно, как это работает внутри. Нигде не нашел, хотел посмотреть исходных код, но там в реализации pass. Диасемблировал цикл - там видно, что при каждой итерации вызывается islice() и затем count(), но все равно непонятно.

Comment: `pass` там относится к случаю `islice(it, start, stop)`, где необходимо пропустить `start` первых элементов, запросив их у `it`, но проигнорировав.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала "вычисляются" значения аргументов, потом они передаются в функцию. Т.е. сначала `itertools.count` возвращает объект-итератор, готовый выдавать значения начиная с 50 с шагом 2, потом этот объект передается `itertools.islice`, который сразу возвращает итератор, готовый выдавать значения из переданного ему итератора, в данном случае первые 10.

Потом `for` последовательно запрашивает значения из итератора возвращенного функцией `islice`, а этот итератор запрашивает значения из итератора, возвращенного функцией `count`.

По сути это ваш первый вариант.

Примеры реализации этих функций есть в документации: [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).